# Image cropiing with the square graphic

Tags: java

```
File originalImage = new File("anyImage.jpg");
BufferedImage newImage = null;

       try{

          newImage = ImageIO.read(originalImage);
          //JPanel np = new JPanel();
          Graphics2D g2 = null;
        //  np.paintComponents(g2);

          g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          int x = (getWidth() - size.width)/2;
          int y = (getHeight() - size.height)/2;

          g2.drawImage(newImage, x, y, this);
          if(showClip){
          if(clip == null)
          clip = new Rectangle(100,100); // set the size of the rectangle

          clip.x = (newImage.getWidth() - clip.width)/2;
          clip.y = (newImage.getHeight() - clip.height)/2;
          int x0 = (newImage.getWidth() - size.width)/2;
          int y0 = (newImage.getHeight() - size.height)/2;
          if(x < x0 || x + clip.width  > x0 + size.width ||
          y < y0 || y + clip.height > y0 + size.height);
       //  return;
         clip.setLocation(x, y);

         g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
         g2.draw(clip);


    }



       } 

       catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

my question is, how can we draw the square graphics on the image which means it should appear something like this, on this code,

The result should be like the image below:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error? What exactly do you need help with? You asked about drawing a square, but it seems like you're already doing that...

Comment: BufferedImage#createGraphics

Comment: I asked about drawing the square on the image as me desired output, but with the code that i send it does not actually give the desired result, it give me this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Well, the NPE is no surprise when you do `Graphics2D g2 = null` and then dereference `g2` on the next line...